# How to build a mono project which depends nunit by Makefile?

Tags: mono, nunit

I'm using mono 2.8.2 with MonoDevelop 2.4.2.

When I try to compile my project using the make files generated by MonoDevlop, I got

> $./configure
>
> Looking for required packages
>
> Checking for package 'nunit'.. ERROR: Package named 'nunit' >= 2.4 not found.
>
> Try adjusting your PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable.

I tried to install nunit to GAC, but it didn't work.

Any idea of what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When compiling with MonoDevelop pkg config is used rather than GAC. Look [here](http://monodevelop.com/FAQ#I_added_an_assembly_to_the_GAC.2c_why_doesn%27t_it_appear_in_the_assemblies_list_when_I_try_to_add_a_reference_in_a_MonoDevelop_project.3f).